# Is reposting a question the only way to get answers if help is urgently needed and there's no activity on the original?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I just asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895848/problem-implementing-css-sprite), and the only guy that was helping me got busy elsewhere and vanished. I have been updating the code in my question, but the question isn't getting views anymore. Editing a question makes it appear on the homepage again, right? I also can't start a bounty because the question isn't old enough yet. What else can I do?

Comment: And why so impatient here as well? You're asking Diago about reposting (after he actually already wrote you should NOT do that), and only 3 minutes later you already [did repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896185/need-help-with-css-sprites-plz-closed). And then when that got closed as a duplicate, you [reposted again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896272/why-the-image-not-getting-displayed-in-the-background-of-the-div). BIG FAIL!

Comment: (New links since [the power outage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage): [Need help with CSS Sprites plz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896522/need-help-with-css-sprites-plz-closed) and [Why the image not getting displayed in the background of the div??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896612/why-the-image-not-getting-displayed-in-the-background-of-the-div))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**

You can set a bounty after two days. The only effect reposting your question will have is having it closed as a duplicate, and aggravating the community.

**However**

SO is in no way a speedy I need help right now solution. The fact that questions are answered quickly is a by product of it's own success. Your question will get answered when it does. If you urgently looking for a solution, SO is **not** the place to come to. No one is under any obligation to answer your question right away, nor is there a priority queue for urgent questions. People answer here for free, and they don't always spend every waking moment on the site.

I know this has been discussed before but right now I can't find all the reference.

Comment: I didnt say anything abt the obligation thingy :/ ...I do realize that sometimes one might not get quick answers which is rare btw but I ask here coz SO is the best place to ask stuff..So should I go ahead n post duplicate anyway ? someone just might answer :/  oh btw what about "Updating ques" that I asked abt..Does it bring up the ques in the list ?

Comment: @Happy Updating it will bring it back into the list, however posting a duplicate is frowned upon and exactly what I told you not to do. It is considered abuse of the system if you do that. Also saying the question is urgent = obligation as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Happy, and [this](http://img.skitch.com/20101009-rrqnii8dqr4ndx2b9kcpducfia.png) and [this](http://img.skitch.com/20101009-brn5jphdinbpi5faydj9545ftg.png) is far too demanding for my liking too. You're just scaring helpful folks away.

Comment: @Happy Soul: Posting a duplicate only gets short-lived attention for the duplicate and does nothing to help your original question. I think it's a better idea to try and give your original question some more thought and update it with anything new that you think might be relevant.