# Why does this question show an incorrect score or vote count?

Tags: bug, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage)

If you look **[at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897396/can-a-table-row-expand-and-close/3897517#3897517)**, you see that the score is `1` (well was when this was written).

I believe I upvoted this question and then canceled my upvote... but I'm not 100%.

I've tried refreshing the page.

Sreenshot:
[image]

But if I click on the vote distribution, I see this:
[image]

Comment: The exact answer is in the linked duplicate here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage/67132#67132

Comment: @Diago - Thanks. So this is sitll ongoing? From reading that thread it sounded like it was finished.