# Answer score miscalculation (0 + -1 = 1) - caching issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, down-votes, up-votes, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a post have an overall score of +1 with 0 up and 1 down votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/how-can-a-post-have-an-overall-score-of-1-with-0-up-and-1-down-votes)

[Iphone resource file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701408/iphone-resource-file-size-limit/4040091#4040091)

Notwithstanding the answer itself, I see 0 vote up, 1 vote down, and a final score of 1.

EDIT:

Proof:

[image: Sum]
[image: Expanded]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post with vote +0/-0.
2. Vote up
3. Cancel up-vote
4. Refresh the page to see it reports a total vote of 1, and the vote splitting becomes +0/-1.

UPDATE:

So now the votes are 0 up, 0 down. We can infer from the timing allowed on vote cancellation that in some cases, a single up-vote, cancelled, produces a "temporary down-vote" which is cached and doesn't get removed for about a day. The sum total of votes remains unchanged post cancellation (and thus erroneous) and the vote detail is also erroneous.

Comment: I see the same thing.

Comment: Jeff Atwood's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68737/upvote-you-agree-you-like/68788#68788 gives this same problem.

Comment: This is a remnant of the outage a week or two ago. It's been reported numerous times. Looking for links now...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67951/post-has-a-score-of-one-shows-votes-of-0-1-and-doesnt-show-up-in-recent-activ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67159/why-does-this-question-show-an-incorrect-score-or-vote-count http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/how-can-a-post-have-an-overall-score-of-1-with-0-up-and-1-down-votes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage

Comment: @PopularDemand. Thanks. I wonder how a week-old outage can change the laws of mathematics today, though.

Comment: @MPelletier,  I misunderstood your initial post. I thought you were referring to the question, posted in September, not the answer, posted today. That's double-odd. I don't know enough about how the SE databases work ("But you don't know anything about how the SE databases work!" "Exactly!") to know if the same corrupted-database-denormalization-voodoo-magic could be responsible.

Comment: Guys, I do not know what you are doing here, but this was discussed several times and you should already know, that it is a caching issue. At least, that's what Jeff says. No, I'm too lazy to search all these dupes. Ok, ok, here is one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/how-can-a-post-have-an-overall-score-of-1-with-0-up-and-1-down-votes

Comment: @LadybugKiller: Thanks. Though it seems to correct itself over time, a case could (I didn't say should) be made for correcting this issue.

Comment: This bug affects only 1-rep posters.

Comment: @KennyTM, now this becomes interesting!

Comment: @MPelletier: Turns out it does not affect only 1-rep posters, but **people who cast the first vote**. I have updated your reproduction procedure to make it clear.

Comment: @KennyTM: So the downvote doesn't even exist?? Wow!

Comment: @sth: Gee, thanks! I don't know if that'll do it, though.

Comment: @MPelletier: The power of the bounty! Instantly fixed and I did even got the bounty rep back. I should do this more often ;)

Comment: Doesn't look like it is fixed now. I'll see if it's deployed by tomorrow.

Comment: @sth: What does Jeff need with a rep-bounty?

Comment: @KennyTM: I tried it here on meta and couldn't reproduce it anymore.

Comment: @sth: It is correctly split into +0/-0, but the vote is still stuck at "1" or "-1" until someone click to view the splitting (or casts a vote).

Comment: @KennyTM: You're right, I did just check the split before. The denormalized count seems to be still not correctly updated.

Comment: @sth: You most likely got your bounty back due to the question getting closed, now that I think about it.

Comment: This is still broken (tested here on meta). KennyTM's last comment still applies: If you upvote, cancel the upvote, and reload the page, the post will show a score of 1. Viewing the vote count split shows +0/-0 and fixes the denormalized score.

Comment: @sth: I noticed it too, but in my experience it was a local caching thing. By refreshing the page the correct number would show.

Comment: @MPelletier: In my tests refreshing the page doesn't help...