# Vote count incorrect - with reproducible steps!

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer score miscalculation (0 + -1 = 1) - caching issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68829/answer-score-miscalculation-0-1-1-caching-issue)

1. Pick a post with **0** votes (question or answer).
2. Vote up, reload page. All is well, the post shows 1 vote, break down +1/-0:
   [image]
3. Cancel the vote by clicking on the upvote arrow again, reload page. Meh.
   [image]

Comment: I've tested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062006/linking-libpng-with-borland-c , and some more on meta. I cannot view vote count on any other site.

Comment: Oh, and related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061997/multiple-loop-variables-in-for-statement-in-obj-c/4062038#4062038. It is showing 1 vote, but when break down 0/-1. My reputation have not increased and recent section showing no vote for today.

Comment: But, I made red arrows!

Comment: True. That is argument enough to make *this* the original question IMO