# Disappearing reputation

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

Previously I had 251 reputation on stackoverflow, then I associated the account with my programmers.stackexchange.com account and got a nice surprise, +100 reputation, yay etc etc, but when I logged in today I had lost the +100 and there was not record of it.

Was the +100 a mistake which got corrected or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you maybe do the association during yesterday's [SO Outage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage)

Comment: It seems so, now my rep is back at 361 again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two accounts with your OpenID hash on Stack Overflow: one with [361 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197657/dutt), and [one with 13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188255/dutt). Did you maybe lose track of the first account? You may want to ask a mod (here, or by emailing team@stackoverflow.com) to merge the accounts.

Comment: Seems this was a temporary glitch, today it's back at 361 again. I completely forgot about the my first account. I flagged your answer, if the first mod that sees this could merge my two accounts it would be great.