# StackOverflow silently redirecting links?

Tags: support

I found a question on StackOverflow which, itself, wasn't particularly interesting, but one of the answers had some good links which I was going to follow up. So I bookmarked it in Google Chrome.

Now, when I click on the bookmark, I'm redirected to a completely unrelated question.

What's going on?

- The original question "All about WCF client" is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896099/all-about-wcf-client
- I get redirected to "Kubuntu 9.10 Android device not properly detected" at [Kubuntu 9.10 Android device not properly detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428713/kubuntu-9-10-android-device-not-properly-detected/3896099#3896099)

Where did the original question go? Why am I redirected to something completely unrelated?

Comment: I think this is because of the recent outage - the post id seem to have been mixed up. Google has a cached version if you search for it: http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22All+about+WCF+client%22

Comment: Unfortunately, the cached version appears to be missing the answers :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching on SO by title, sorted by date, gets you the current ID: [All about wcf client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896436/all-about-wcf-client)

(Oddly, [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YIY-AJLpQy4J:stackoverflow.com/questions/3896099/all-about-wcf-client+site:stackoverflow.com) even shows you a user id for "delivering" that is now [a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470910/delivering). Searching that name [on the user pages](https://stackoverflow.com/users), gets you the right user though, who only has a single post right now.)

Comment: I accepted this one because you answered the most important part of my question: "Where did the original question go?". Marc gets an upvote for answering the other half.

Answer (score 5):

This probably relates to the outage on Saturday. A small amount of data was screwy, so shortcuts from that interval will be wrong (they may have a different ID)

[See here for full details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage)