# Post has a score of one, shows votes of +0/-1 and doesn't show up in recent activity

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I see a downvote on my answer but nothing recorded in my recent activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67905/why-do-i-see-a-downvote-on-my-answer-but-nothing-recorded-in-my-recent-activity)

Just came across a situation for a question I answered on SO. When I open that answer, I see the below icon on it:

[image: total vote counter displaying "1"]

But when I click for the up/down vote numbers, it shows me the below image:

[image: vote differential counter displaying "0/-1"]

Is this a bug in Stack Overflow, or something else?

If it would help, the question that I answered is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958647/displaying-images-in-jcombobox/3958677#3958677).

Comment: (Stealing balpha's comment from a "1 year, 12 months" post:) I'm pretty sure that, had you used a more descriptive title, the dupe would have shown up in the "related questions" suggestion list.

Comment: @Popular Demand - Yes, Possibly it could've shown if my question statement was correct, but I did not know what to add for this question title. Thanks anyway for editing tough, but I am still not clear on if this bug is still present or will it get automatically corrected after sometime?

Comment: @Popular Demand - I never had this situation till today, but interestingly, today, this happened to me twice for two different answers. Funny tough.

Comment: this bug was introduced [pretty recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage). I don't know what kind of progress is being made in cleaning up these last few cases.