# Votes registered but not reflected in reputation after outage

Tags: support, voting, outage

On the weekend of your recent outage I had received a couple of upvotes for my answers (for example, this one: *[I'm looking for internationalization verification tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707538/im-looking-for-internationalization-verification-tool/3889739#3889739)* ) but my reputation points for the votes were rolled back although the vote count in my profile does reflect the votes.

Same in the opposite direction: on the day of the outage I have upvoted the answer at *[What is practical use of IDEA MPS and Eclipse Xtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355289/what-is-practical-use-of-idea-mps-and-eclipse-xtext/3884458#3884458)* and seems like my vote hasn't been recounted since then although when I visit that page, I can see the answer as upvoted by me.

I have previously [commented on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage/67132#67132) but to no effect.

Could you please check this? Thanks