# Stackoverflow.com is down?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, outage

Seems like stackoverflow.com and other Q&A sites are down.
The following is displayed:

```
Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance
```

But is it really just maintenance or is it an outage?

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/278498281124921344

Comment: Who cares? It'll be back up eventually. (Edit: Ah, ChrisF has the answer)

Comment: PANIC!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It's network wide, apparently.

Comment: Why did my question got closed for too localized as this is a website for support. So an outage requires support. Others have posted similar question in the past.

Comment: Because the question has been answered, and this question won't be useful anymore when the site is back up in a short while.

Comment: Then how come all the previous questions of the same type didn't get closed? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage?rq=1 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20377/stackoverflow-com-down?rq=1

Comment: Ultimately, closed or not, the answer is the same: we know about it, we understand it, we're working really hard to fix it as quickly as possible.

Comment: @qwertzguy So everytime StackOverflow has an issue we can expect someone to post an identical question demanding answers? Think of the reputation! /s

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [@StackStatus twitter feed](https://twitter.com/stackstatus/status/278498281124921344):

> We're aware of the #stackoverflow instability, the servers are running under extremely heavy load and will be more stable in a few minutes.

The [StackOverflow Pingdom page](http://stats.pingdom.com/w2oc4thvox7s/73676) is showing the downtime too.